# Transform CBPeripheral's UUID to string format :

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, core-bluetooth

I am trying to transform a CBPeripheral's UUID to string format:

```
CBPeripheral*         peripheral;

NSString *pUuid = (__bridge NSString *)(CFUUIDCreateString(nil, peripheral.UUID));
```

but i got this error:

```
Incompatible pointer types passing retainable parameter of type 'NSString *' to a CF functions expecting 'CFUUIDRef' (aka 'const struct _CFUUID *') type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`peripheral.UUID` is deprecated as of OSX 10.9 per the [Apple Documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CBPeripheral/UUID)

To accomplish what you are trying to do, you use:

```
[peripheral.identifier UUIDString]
```